# mapping two tables into one java object using hibernate xml mapping

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

I want to have a single java object that is mapped to 2 database tables using Hibernate **XML** mapping.

```
Table1 columns: (id, row_num, t1c1)

Table2 columns: (id, row_num, t2c1)
```

I want to have a java object with below attributes:

id, row_num, t**1**c1, t**2**c1

Most of the example I find with one-to-one relation, is one object containing the other as a sub-object:

[example1](https://www.codejava.net/frameworks/hibernate/hibernate-one-to-one-with-primary-key-xml-mapping-example)
[example2](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/hibernate/hibernate-one-to-one-relationship-example-xml-mapping-and-annotation/)

I wonder if I can join the two tables in the XML mapping (The mapping has to work for read/write).

Comment: Why do you want to use outdated xml mapping but not annotations?

Comment: I am working on a legacy project and do not want to make huge changes. Their Table1 has reached max row size, hence Table2 is created with the extra column.

Comment: do you have any relation between the tables ?

Comment: its 1-1 relation. id & row_num are unique. 1 row in table1 maps to 1 row in table2

Comment: If you want to get a list of your objects from the database, should it be filled by rows of both tables? Or is it (virually) onyl one table whose columns are spread over those two tables?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. created table2 bcz Table1 one reached max row capacity. So yes 2 actual database tables. On the java side, I want table1 object to have columns of table 2 as attributes (hence looking to join them).